# Bulk insert .csv - fieldterminator

Tags: sql, sqlbulkcopy

I have .csv which content is like this

```
"aa839","340000","2350444"
```

When I do the `BULK INSERT`, I use `FIELDTERMINATOR = ','`
Thus, the data has quote `"`.

I want to remove the quote `"`, so that my database has only `aa839, 340000, 2350444`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dont bother about replacing while doing bulk insert , you can replace later after bulk insert . So do bulk insert as it is originally and later fire update query as below. This is the fastest way too

```
update table set field= REPLACE(field, 'search', 'replace');
```

where search is "" and replace is blank

Answer (score 0):

while reading the file replace all (") with blank (), then replace (,) with space ( )

Answer (score 0):

here's how to do it with powershell:

```
Get-Content inputfilename | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '\"', ''} | 
Set-Content outputfilename
```